# Android Studio not launching Android emulator on AMD Ryzen

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, emulation, virtualization

[AMD Ryzen 3600 CPU, Win10 Professional, MSI B450 Gaming Plus]

So, hello people.
This problem is seemingly a known one but it came with a twist here.
I'll try to keep it as simple as possible:

1. I installed Docker for a hobby project of mine. Docker needs Hyper-V to be turned on in the Windows features so I did that. It said I need to turn on virtualization in Bios, did that too.
2. Later on, I installed Android studio which greeted me with an error message about "HAXM" not being able to install itself. I ignored that since I had no idea what that is.
3. I started a plain new Android native (Java) project in Android studio, set up an emulator which said I have to turn off Hyper-V in order for it to work. I did that. Didn't use Docker since, even removed docker cause the app is currently my priority.
4. The native app worked! Then I tried to make a Flutter app in Android studio. Installed the Dart and Flutter plugins but the virtual device I set up for the other project wasn't visible. Flutter doctor said I should set the SDK path for Flutter (meaning setting the Path and another environment variable). Did that. Emulator worked.
5. Yesterday I started my PC and tried running the Flutter app. When I launch the emulator in Android Studio it says:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware
>   acceleration! Please ensure Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is
>   properly installed and usable. CPU acceleration status: GVM is not
>   installed on this machine More info on configuring VM acceleration on
>   Windows:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows
>   If you are using an Intel CPU: please check that virtualization is
>   enabled in the BIOS and that HAXM is installed and usable. Note: if
>   Hyper-V or Credential Guard is enabled, the emulator will not work
>   with HAXM. See
>   https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/105#issuecomment-470927735 for
>   info on how to disable Credential Guard. If you are using an AMD CPU
>   or need to run alongside Hyper-V-based apps such as Docker, we
>   recommend using Windows Hypervisor Platform.General information on
>   acceleration:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.

6. The text says I should have "Windows Hypervisor Platform" turned on. I didn't have that turned on in the Windows features and it worked nonetheless! Well, I still turned that on cause it seems that's recommended for AMD CPUs. Now **Hyper-V is turned off**, the **Hypervisor Platform is turned on**, **virtualization in BIOS is turned on**, (**Windows Defender memory management is turned off**, too, since many suggestions pointed out that's important?).
7. Emulator still doesnt work and if I try to install HAXM through Android Studio->Settings->System Settings->Android SDK->SDK Tools it says:

> HAXM installation failed. To install HAXM follow the instructions
>   found at:
>   https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows Installer log is located at
>   C:\Users\JaySON\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log7.txt Installer log
>   contents:
>
> This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)
>   or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
>   Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the
>   Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

Now I have no idea what to do. Some people sugggest I should turn ON Hyper-V, some suggest I should turn on Hyper-V AND the platform, some suggest I should turn both OFF, some suggest I should turn both off AND that's only possible through various CLI commands etc. Help. ;-;

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I just went in with the almost typical approach of "let's just push buttons until it works". I disabled the Windows Hypervisor Platform (Hyper-V was still disabled), it didn't work. I enabled both, didn't work. I disabled both and then enabled Hyper-V without the Platform. THIS WORKED. However, to anyone reading this: It's now what it's supposed to be doing! So if you have the same problem, just try all possible combinations of those two. Afaik there's no correct way of doing that. Even people with a Ryzen CPU like myself got different results. For some it worked to just disable both, for some it only works if both are present, some only work with HAXM installed even though that's for Intel CPUs and for me it worked just by re-enabling Hyper-V for the third time.

"Have you tried turning it off and on again" with extra steps